# What is the status bonus to damage when a ranger with Gravity Weapon active uses Power Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, ranger

As title.

[Power Attack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=359) says "you deal an extra die of weapon damage".

[Gravity Weapon](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=770) states that the first Strike each round gains a "status bonus to damage equal to twice the number of weapon damage dice".

So if a 20th level Ranger has a major striking rune on their weapon, the Gravity Weapon spell active, and then uses Power Attack as their first action in a round, they'll deal 7[W] damage dice (4[W] from their rune, and an extra 3[W] from Power Attack). Does this then mean that the status bonus from Gravity Weapon is 14?

Or is there some hidden gotcha that means that the extra weapon damage dice don't count towards Gravity Weapon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it. From [the section on Damage in rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=226):

> Effects based on a weapon’s number of damage dice include only the weapon’s damage die plus any extra dice from a striking rune. They don’t count extra dice from abilities, critical specialization effects, property runes, weapon traits, or the like.

So it's capped at 8.

Comment: Doesn't power attack increase the number of weapon damage die, though?

Comment: @Feathercrown Yes, that is how it's phrased, but the rule quote mentions specific dice are considered when counting them for bonus damage... the weapon’s damage **die** plus any extra dice **from a striking rune**. No mention is made of abilities adding to the count. Referring to adding Weapon Dice (such as Power Attack) allows an ability's damage to scale with the weapon damage size, not to boost other abilities that count your dice